# Pandas shape mismatch (filter, assign values to multiple columns) can't figure it out

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been searching around for hours and can't figure this out.

This doesn't work

```
df.loc[(df['Test Col'] == True) & (df[['Col 1 (F)','Col 2 (F)']].max(axis=1) > today),['New Suggested Due Date', 'Test Col','Reviewed','Section Source']] = [df[['Col 1 (F)','Col 2 (F)']].max(axis=1), 'False', 'True', 'error test']
```

This one works

```
df.loc[(df['Test Col'] == True) & (df[['Col 1 (F)','Col 2 (F)']].max(axis=1) > today),['New Suggested Due Date', 'Test Col','Reviewed','Section Source']] = [pd.Timestamp.now().date() + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(n=1), 'False','True', 'error test']
```

This stopped working when I started chaining from 'New Suggested Due Date', it was just that one but then I added the others and it did work but not when I try to get the max of those two columns or use df[any column] and add offsets to it. If I remove the chaining it will work again.

The columns are dates:

```
col 1 (F)   col 2 (F)   Test Col   Reviewed     Section Source
4/22/2023   5/4/2023      True       False
4/22/2023   5/4/2023      True       False
4/22/2023   5/4/2023      True       False
3/29/2023   5/13/1913     True       False
3/29/2023   3/25/2023     True       False
2/15/2023   3/25/2023     True       False
```

Output:

```
New Suggested Due Date    Test Col    Reviewed   Section Source
     5/4/2023               False      True        Error Test
     5/4/2023               False      True        Error Test     
     5/4/2023               False      True        Error Test
     3/29/2023              False      True        Error Test
     3/29/2023              False      True        Error Test
     3/25/2023              False      True        Error Test
```

I want the output to update the `New Suggested Due Date` column with the max date from col 1 and 2 and then make it the end of the next month, then also update the other columns `Test col`, `Reviewed`, `Section Source`. Which it can it if I don't use last `df[['Physical Construction Completed (F)','Inservice Activation (F)']].max(axis=1)` part. This is when it breaks.

Any suggestions will probably help grow hair back on my head :(

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected output. ?

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: is the "Output" section supposed to be your desired output? that doesn't seem to match the description: `"then make it the end of the next month"`